# AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server

Tags: php, apache, xampp

My Apache keeps shutting down while uploading photos to one of my websites.
I currently use XAMPP, v.3.3.0. I have had issues in the past where MYSQL wouldn't start properly, so I am currently using an older version instead of the newest.

```
[Sat Oct 29 21:03:19.067516 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10564:tid 392] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sat Oct 29 21:03:21.089915 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10196:tid 424] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sat Oct 29 21:03:21.115924 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10564:tid 392] AH00430: Parent: Child process 10196 exited successfully.
[Sat Oct 29 21:03:36.304642 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15964:tid 440] AH00455: Apache/2.4.53 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1n PHP/7.4.29 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Oct 29 21:03:36.304642 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15964:tid 440] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Mar 16 2022 15:48:38
[Sat Oct 29 21:03:36.304642 2022] [core:notice] [pid 15964:tid 440] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Sat Oct 29 21:03:36.307644 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15964:tid 440] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 14140
[Sat Oct 29 21:03:36.675672 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14140:tid 444] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

I edited my php.ini file so I could upload more files at once, I need to upload around 280 files everytime. Even if I upload one file now, it won't work properly.
This is my current .htaccess file (I think it's not interfering, but still showing it):

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 403 https://peelleuters.nl/403

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ artikel.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

Options -Indexes
```

Please help..

Comment: What does your system log say at that time? Could be an issue with the system running out of memory for example.

Comment: @arkascha I edited the max_file_uploads in php.ini so I could upload more than 300 photos at once. I also edited the upload_max_filesize to 8000M.

Comment: I understood that from your question. Do you have an answer to what I asked above?

Comment: @arkascha  I assume this? The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{6B3B8D23-FA8D-40B9-8DBD-B950333E2C52}
 and APPID 
{4839DDB7-58C2-48F5-8283-E1D1807D0D7D}
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE SID (S-1-5-19) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

Comment: Sounds like an MS-Windows system. I have never been able to make sense of their strangely twisted phrasing of something as simple as an error message. Sorry. But that seems to try to express something about permissions ...

Comment: @arkascha but what am I able to do to fix this??

Comment: Sorry, I can't help there. I have little experience with MS-Windows systems.

Comment: @arkascha i appreciate your comments though, have a nice day!